# What do I need in my ~/.vimrc to make neovim act like vim?

Tags: neovim

I'd like to be able to use Neovim with my usual Vim configuration by running `nvim -u ~/.vimrc`.

However, Neovim seems to introduce a few changes to the default Vim key bindings, such as `Y` no longer yanking the entire line but yanking only to end of line.

What do I need to put in my `~/.vimrc` to "undo" this and any similar changes to the defaults that Neovim? The code should have no effect in Vim, of course, just in Neovim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no simple command which will make neovim behave like vim.  However, most of the changes are documented at `:help vim-differences`, reproduced below.

You can unset and unmap them as needed, as an example I have included a handful of the options which cause a major noticeable change in behavior.

```
let loaded_matchit = 1
nunmap! Y
nunmap! <C-L>
xunmap! *
xunmap! #
nunmap! &
set nosmarttab noautoindent noautoread nohidden
set nohlsearch noincsearch joinspaces noruler laststatus=1
set mouse=
```

Some changes cannot be altered, like the very different `:term` function or the omission of `vim9script`.

---

```
==============================================================================
2. Defaults                             *nvim-defaults*

- Filetype detection is enabled by default. This can be disabled by adding
  ":filetype off" to |init.vim|.
- Syntax highlighting is enabled by default. This can be disabled by adding
  ":syntax off" to |init.vim|.

- 'autoindent' is enabled
- 'autoread' is enabled
- 'background' defaults to "dark" (unless set automatically by the terminal/UI)
- 'backspace' defaults to "indent,eol,start"
- 'backupdir' defaults to .,~/.local/share/nvim/backup// (|xdg|), auto-created
- 'belloff' defaults to "all"
- 'compatible' is always disabled
- 'complete' excludes "i"
- 'cscopeverbose' is enabled
- 'directory' defaults to ~/.local/share/nvim/swap// (|xdg|), auto-created
- 'display' defaults to "lastline,msgsep"
- 'encoding' is UTF-8 (cf. 'fileencoding' for file-content encoding)
- 'fillchars' defaults (in effect) to "vert:│,fold:·,sep:│"
- 'formatoptions' defaults to "tcqj"
- 'fsync' is disabled
- 'hidden' is enabled
- 'history' defaults to 10000 (the maximum)
- 'hlsearch' is enabled
- 'incsearch' is enabled
- 'joinspaces' is disabled
- 'langnoremap' is enabled
- 'langremap' is disabled
- 'laststatus' defaults to 2 (statusline is always shown)
- 'listchars' defaults to "tab:> ,trail:-,nbsp:+"
- 'nrformats' defaults to "bin,hex"
- 'ruler' is enabled
- 'sessionoptions' includes "unix,slash", excludes "options"
- 'shortmess' includes "F", excludes "S"
- 'showcmd' is enabled
- 'sidescroll' defaults to 1
- 'smarttab' is enabled
- 'startofline' is disabled
- 'switchbuf' defaults to "uselast"
- 'tabpagemax' defaults to 50
- 'tags' defaults to "./tags;,tags"
- 'ttimeoutlen' defaults to 50
- 'ttyfast' is always set
- 'undodir' defaults to ~/.local/share/nvim/undo// (|xdg|), auto-created
- 'viewoptions' includes "unix,slash", excludes "options"
- 'viminfo' includes "!"
- 'wildmenu' is enabled
- 'wildoptions' defaults to "pum,tagfile"

- |man.vim| plugin is enabled, so |:Man| is available by default.
- |matchit| plugin is enabled. To disable it in your config: >
    :let loaded_matchit = 1

- |g:vimsyn_embed| defaults to "l" to enable Lua highlighting


Default Mappings ~
                            *default-mappings*
Nvim creates the following default mappings at |startup|. You can disable any
of these in your config by simply removing the mapping, e.g. ":unmap Y".
>
    nnoremap Y y$
    nnoremap <C-L> <Cmd>nohlsearch<Bar>diffupdate<Bar>normal! <C-L><CR>
    inoremap <C-U> <C-G>u<C-U>
    inoremap <C-W> <C-G>u<C-W>
    xnoremap * y/\V<C-R>"<CR>
    xnoremap # y?\V<C-R>"<CR>
    nnoremap & :&&<CR>
```

Comment: `Y` for yanking till the end of the line makes logical sense when looking at the behavior of `D`, or `D` should remove the full line as well. It feels inconsistent to me. I wonder why the original authors of `vim` never corrected that behavior.

Comment: vim favors above all else, compatibility with vi